# SASS is not working in Visual Studio Code 1.33.0

Tags: css, sass

Started using visual studio code for SASS. Created the simple HTML as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
        <title>SCSS Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.scss">
       </head>
       <body>
           <header>
               <h1> Hello SCSS </h1>
               <button>Hello</button>
           </header>
           <div>
             <button>Submit</button>
             <div>
               <h1> Our Contact Info </h1>
               <p class="">This is our info</p>
             </div>
           </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Added a folder named "styles" where I have created "main.scss" file as below and used "Live Sass Compiler" extension to generate the CSS file and map file.

### SCSS File:

```
$primaryHeaderBack : lightblue;

header {
    background: $primaryHeaderBack;
}
```

### Expected Output:

Header Background color is not showing light blue but white. In order to see the desired output what should I do? Please help me.

Comment: I think you should be calling your `.css` file (that is automatically created by the Compiler) in your html, not your `.scss` file :-)

Comment: That means we are using normal html css, but there are many advantages of using SCSS, like using variables, nesting atc.

Comment: When you use sass (with the 'live sass compiler') this creates a .css file in the same folder (or somewhere else depending on how you've set the plugin up) for your website to use. You're still using sass to create it so you'll still be able to use variable and nesting.

Comment: Hi, Coops... thanks for your advise... It worked... Instead using .scss file its .css, we should use. Later I thought in your way, I found it make sense, we will write .scss it will generate .css which we should use as a link in our HTML. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Moibabrata ,@coops asked you to link your CSS file to your HTML because, Once the live SASS compiler starts the SASS files gets converted to CSS files, As HTML file cannot understand **.sass**, You have to use **.css**, But don't worry, Your **.css** file will have everything you type inside your .sass file.

You don't have to ever modify your .css file, Whatever you do in the **.sass** file will get Updated Automatically in the **.css** file.

So Instead of this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.scss">`

**Use** : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">`

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is you **" linked .scss file"**
the browser can't read .scss file it always read .css file.
so you must link .css file in your HTML file.

then start watching on your .scss file for compiling.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbm98.jpg)

completing these step you will check your browser.
I hope you will get the expected result.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> you cant use sass into html file directly, because it not works. But
>   how you can use a sass file into html??

SCSS files are files which need to be converted to CSS files (so a browser knows how to use them). You can see SCSS as any other high-level language like C#; you compile / build it into a language for the target (in this case the browser).

The answer is you must to convert your sass file into a css file. You can do this by cmd.
First, open cmd and get in project folder, then write this command in cmd:

```
sass scss\your_scss_filename css\your_css_filename
```

After you run this command, you can see its output in the folder.
Good luck.